# Language switcher doesn't work

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a fresh D8.64+Bootstrap 3 installation, after enable multilingual modules, add languages and config language dection and content/menu translation, I placed the defualt language switcher to the primary sidebar. Then I translated some contents and menus to other languages. Strangely, when I switch languages, nothing happened, even no changes in the admin interface (only the default English)! I changed the theme, changed the language detection order, cleared cache...it was the same. I downloaded a dropdown language block, it even doesn't show up when I place it on the sidebar (but can show in bartik theme). I searched on internet for hours, but no luck. Could anybody have clue of solution?

[image: Language switcher not working]

Comment: What does sitename/sv return?

Comment: I translated the site name, but when I switch the language, the site name remains the original one (English).

Comment: Yes but did you see that the Swedish site works?

Comment: No it does not. For instance, the Swedish homepage url is www.DOMAINNAME.com/sv, if i direct to this url, it still show default English for everything. If I edit this page to Swedish( title, body), then when i direct to English homepage, it also shows Swedish. Anyway I can only have one language.

Comment: You have something wrong in your multilingual setup. Try to se Drupal.org they have a multilingual guide and see if you have done something wrong

Comment: In D8, the multilingual setup shouldn’t be so complicated, I  have checked everything according to instructions on drupal.org as well as a very clear instructions as below: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/d8-multi-lingual/, but nothing happened. This is not the first time I install D8, never met this before.

Comment: Sounds quite strange, try to go to status report and see if you have some site problems

Comment: I checked, just one warning found: PHP OPCODE CACHING, nothing else wrong. Translation update status is up to date.

Comment: I deleted one language and reinstalled, unfortunately no changes. Even for the backend interface is just the same, only English. I don't know if this is the drupal version related? The server has default D installer is D8.64.

Answer (score 0):

I finally sort this out：in the language detection and selection set the url first then others. Deleted the languages and reinstalled them. It suddenly worked. I even don't know why. Thank you @jdrupal very much for your patience and help!!